# Metrics configuration for 2 networks: WAN & 4G on Windows 10

Tags: networking, routing, adapter, wan

I am currently in charge of designing a network solution. I am fairly basic at networking but im sure this solution should work.

On our previous development, we had thought that our machine would only need 1 connection that us and our partner could use together, which then connected via Mikrotik and forwarded to our PC. the Mikrotik was there to serve PPTP service so we could remote the machine and use IP Camera at the same time for monitoring purposes. Turns out, our partner was using M2M 4G Modem connected to their WAN. this has led them to bypass our Mikrotik since *configuring is too much of a hassle* they said, plus their WAN won't let us connect to our server, making it useless.

my solution is that our machine is connected to 2 separate networks. 1 corporate WAN by 4G modem LAN, (the PC needs to be in the same address as the M2M provide (10.15.x.x) in which why we couldn't connect both to Mikrotik as it just gives a single IP from DHCP). and 1 public internet (either by 4G or FO, as long as its connected to our Mikrotik's eth1 as internet input). the machine is running on Windows 10. Since I couldn't get a hold on the WAN. [Here is the topology that I used to replicate the solution Topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3NgQ.png)

Since I couldn't get a hand on the WAN, I replaced the M2M & its WAN with another PC running webserver.

It does works, but. I need to adjust the metrics on each the network's adapter configuration whenever I want to use each of the network. For example, when the Webserver's network is the priority, I won't be able to ping / access google. and vice versa.

Is there any solution to my ongoing problem? I'm sure this solution would actually work, its just that I haven't found the right solution

Really appreciate any sort of solution / insights to my problem. Have a great day

Comment: What you need is a switch that supports VLANs, specifically allow specific devices, to access separate VLANs. I am guessing you don't have the budget for a LEVEL 3 CISCO switch, because if you had that budget, I am guessing you would have already gone with that solution.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I haven't really thought of using a vlan. and yes I don't the budget for that. the thing is, the WAN needs us to be in a specific address given by the M2M. Thus why we opted to use a usb to ethernet adapter so the port would have the correct IP as needed. I forgot to add this to the first post

Comment: So you have 2 ethernet adapters but in my own recent tests, I found that Windows does not like having 2 adapters, assigned to two entirely different subnets.  I assume that's what has been done?

Comment: Yes, I am connecting 2 different adapters and assigned to different networks. It does works but if I tried to access the other network with lower priority (higher metrics). It will return an RTO. most likely because windows is trying to search for my request in the network with higher priority. I believe there should be a solution for this (automatic switching priorities). But I still haven't found the solution to that